# SQL Case: Set different outcomes based on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Case:

```
SELECT ID, ValidTo,

CASE
WHEN ValidTo <= DATEADD(DAY, +40, GETDATE())THEN 'About To Expire'
WHEN ValidTo < GETDATE() THEN 'Expired'
ELSE 'Approved' END AS ContractStatusID

FROM Contract
```

I would like to have 3 cases, where the first one is 'About to expire', that should be if the *`ValidTo`* is set to expire within 40 days from now todays date. The second case should be if the date is before todays date and therefore is 'expired'. The rest should be set to Approved. Now I've tried both `DateAdd` and `DateDiff`, but I can't seem too get it to work. The above code, sets everything that is about to expire or *has expired* to 'About to expire'. If I remove the `<` before `ValidTo = DateAdd`, everything gets set to 'expired'. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, so thankful for any solutions/help!

Comment: Have you tried to changed first and second branches

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: @TheImpaler SQL Server

Comment: Yes, as @Sergey says swapping the first and second `WHEN` clauses shoud do the trick.

Comment: @Sergey Sorry, it does work i'm tired today haha thank you so much, that was a simple fix!

Comment: To elaborate on @Sergey 's comment, a `CASE` expression is resolved in order, and with return the *first* TRUE result. As `ValidTo <= DATEADD(DAY, +40, GETDATE())` will always be TRUE when `ValidTo < GETDATE() ` is `TRUE`, then the `WHEN` for `ValidTo < GETDATE() ` can never be returned; as `'About To Expire'` would have already evaluated to TRUE. You want to always have your most restrictive clauses in a `CASE` expression first, and the least restrictive at the end; this is especially true when clauses overlap (like the above).

Comment: @Larnu thank you, that makes sense! I didn't know that, so that's great to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    validTo,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, validTo, GETDATE()) <=0 THEN 'Expired'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, validTo, GETDATE()) <=40 THEN 'About To Expire'
        ELSE 'Approved'
    END AS ContractStatusID,
    DATEDIFF(day,validTo,GETDATE()) AS DaysLeft
FROM Contract
```